# MSAccess Query weird behavior

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create an MS Access query and I'm encountering something very strange that I've never seen before. The field type is Long Integer. When I try to convert it from Integer to String, the Query returns something completely different...

This is what the query results look like. Anyone know what's causing this weird behavior?

```
Cstr(ID)| ID
 298    | 104
 327    | 1003
 299    | 105
 331    | 1007
```

There are other integer fields when placed in Cstr() are working correctly. It's just this one field that's not showing the correct value.

Edit: I should also mention that the source table for this query is a linked Sharepoint list.

Comment: Can you create a small sample database that replicates the behaviour, upload it to a file sharing site like [wikisend.com](http://wikisend.com) and post the link as a comment?

Comment: Try changing Cstr(ID) to CStr(Trim(ID)) and see if that changes anything.  You might be picking up invisible noise in the field.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this behavior in a new database. I tried to copy the table to a new database and the problem went away in the new database.

Comment: Nope, The CStr(Trim(ID)) does not work. It's still giving those weird numbers. This is really bizarre because it's only happening to that one field.

Comment: Is your ID field a field in a related table?  For example, if you have a Customer field in a Sharepoint table that is linked to another table of customers, although you SEE the customer name, what you retrieve programatically is the ID field from the customer table.  It's been awhile, but I don't think I ever found a way for it to return the field value itself.